# Read .NET configuration from database

Tags: .net, sql-server, configuration

The .NET 2.0 and up configuration system is quite powerful and extensible - as long as you don't want to change the fact it all comes from XML files in the filesystem.

In my requirement, I cannot change files since my app runs in a managed environment outside my reach - but I could change the SQL Server database.

So I am looking at storing configuration files or sections in a SQL table - but how can I tie the .NET 2.0 configuration system into this??

Is there a way to write a "custom config provider" that will read its config sections not from a *.config file in the file system, but from a table in the SQL database??

I've been looking at creating my own custom ConfigurationSection or ConfigurationElement, or even a custom Configuration per se - but it seems I always end up back at the point that I can extend the config-system in the filesystem as much as I like, but I can't make it read my XML fragments from a database table.....

What am I missing? Has someone done this already and care to explain / share?

Thanks!
Marc

PS: I also tried to just read the config XML into a string, and then deserializing it into the appropriate e.g. ServiceModelConfigSection - that doesn't work, unfortunately, because the ConfigSection base class somehow doesn't implement a method that is required for it to be XML serializable ........ (YIKES!!!)

Comment: But wouldn't uou have the issue of whereabouts to set the config information for your SQL connection? Once you've got a connection to the DB you could just load whatever settings you need. App.Config isn't much more than a lookup table.

Comment: Yes - what I'm trying to accomplish is to configure WCF services from within a database. Those WCF config files are QUITE LARGE AND COMPLEX - and I really don't want to break down all that stuff into atomic assigments --> I'd like to read the config XML from database and apply it.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense, I can see why WCF configs from a db would be handy. I suspect you are right and there must be some way to get App.Config read in as a stream or block of XML instead of a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an article here that talks about doing what you are talking about:

> http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Redirecting-Configuration-with-a-Custom-Provider.id-291932.html

In summary what they do is create a derived version of ProtectedConfigurationProvider, which is typically used to encrypt .config files. In the Decrypt method, instead of decrypting the configuration information, it's retrieved from a database.

Comment: +1 - thanks, very interesting! Can't quite make sense of the "ProtectedConfigurationProvider" as a base class just yet.... but I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hi Keltex - it works - mostly - but it's a pretty awful HACK in my opinion..... too bad there's no "proper", nice, official way to directly plug in config providers into the .NET config system.....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same xml parsing .NET uses when reading the web.config and configuration sections with some reflection.

Here is the [sample code](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/DotNetConfigurationFromDatabase) to do it.

Here is a class that you want represented in xml.

```
public class TestConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("optionalProperty", DefaultValue = "defaultValue")]
    public string OptionalProperty
    {
        get { return (string)base["optionalProperty"]; }
        set { base["optionalProperty"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("requiredProperty", IsRequired = true)]
    public string RequiredProperty
    {
        get { return (string)base["requiredProperty"]; }
        set { base["requiredProperty"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is how you instantiate this ConfigurationSection using XML from a string (or a database). This was taken from the tests on GitHub that was linked in the blog post above.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_build_configuration_with_default_value_set()
{
    var result = _configurationSectionBuilder
        .BuildSection<TestConfiguration>("<config requiredProperty=\"required\" optionalProperty=\"setValue\"></config>");

    Assert.AreEqual("setValue", result.OptionalProperty);
}
```

You get all the .NET lift with this approach using the System.Configuration namespace.

Comment: Nice!  This worked great for me.  The only gotcha involved the need to make sure my XML didn't have any leading CRLFs/whitespace.  Though some people say that relying on private CLR methods like this is dangerous, it's a lot less sketchy for me than the code I'm trying to refactor away.  This makes a great scaffold to prop some of this stuff up while I attack the main problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try with the "Configuration Service for .NET Applications and WCF Services", is part of the StockTrader 2.0 sample app from MSFT:

[StockTrader 2.0 Configuration Service overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd164388)

[StockTrader 2.0 Configuration Service documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/6/486b4b4f-5a87-4b5c-beec-455290f83274/ConfigServiceTechnicalGuide.pdf)

[Download StockTrader 2.0 for .NET 4.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/9/8192E4B2-1054-45CD-9AC8-94CE2C777264/StockTraderSetup.msi)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cinchoo framework](http://www.cinchoo.com) for your needs.

It supports reading and writing configuration entries to File, Registry, INI, Database etc.

Here is the simple way to define and use the configuration object using Cinchoo framework

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    #region NameSpaces

    using System;
    using Cinchoo.Core.Configuration;

    #endregion NameSpaces

    [ChoConfigurationSection("sample")]
    public class SampleConfigSection : ChoConfigurableObject
    {
        [ChoPropertyInfo("name", DefaultValue="Mark")]
        public string Name;

        [ChoPropertyInfo("message", DefaultValue="Hello World!")]
        public string Message;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SampleConfigSection sampleConfigSection = new SampleConfigSection();
        Console.WriteLine(sampleConfigSection.ToString());
    }

}
```

Very first time, when you run the application, Cinchoo framework automatically generates the configuration section as below. Then onwards, you can control them either through configuration source or by code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="sample" type="Cinchoo.Core.Configuration.ChoNameValueSectionHandler, Cinchoo.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7dacd80ff3e33de" />
  </configSections>
  <sample>
    <add key="name" value="Mark" />
    <add key="message" value="Hello World!" />
  </sample>
</configuration>
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try ready-to-use [JsonRepositoryConfiguration](https://github.com/Shoeib-Yarmand/Json-repository-configuration) Nuget package which does exactly that. It also has a auto-refresh feature and works pretty much like configuration form JSON config files, only it expects the JSON config from **your** repository which can in turn bring the data from any internal/external storage including making a database call, API call etc.

You can mix different configuration provides (like this one and JSON config files) and use them together should you like to. Confession: I am the author.